# Which versions of Windows know the API function CopyFile2?

Tags: windows, winapi

MSDN describes a [CopyFile2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which it suggests in the article on [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) if I want to copy files across a LAN. (which I do)

I understand that this function should be exported by kernel32.dll but I cannot find it in the export of kernel32.dll of my Windows XP installation. Since the article does not state which Windows version it requires but says "This documentation is preliminary and is subject to change." I guess that probably means it requires something more recent than Windows XP.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new in Windows 8.  Unfortunately, MSDN doesn't make these new things clearly distinguishable

Answer (score 1):

The CopyFileEx link you provided says:

> CopyFile2 was introduced with Windows Developer Preview and Windows Server Developer Preview.

I'm guessing it's very new at this point - possibly only in Win8 dev preview.

Comment: I remembered reading that but could not find it on the CopyFile2 page afterwards. So it was on CopyFileEx...